# How to pass data from child to second parent view controller without using NotificationCenter in swift

Tags: swift, controller, navigation

My situation is, I have a navigation controller(nv) with root view controller(rootVC). And another view controller(firstChildVC) pushed to rootVC. And one more view controller(secondChildVC) pushed to firstChildVC. (In real case, I have more subsequence child view controllers) After API calls and some calculations in secondChildVC, I need to pass some data from secondChildVC back to rootVC and popToRootViewController to show some data.

I don't think delegate and closures are good choice in this case. The only thing I could come up with is using NotificationCenter. Just what to know is there any better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The whole point of delegates and notification center are to avoid any direct coupling between classes. Those are a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside the SecondVC then pop to root

```
if let root = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? RootVC {
    root.sendData(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three valid ways to do this without overly tightly coupling things:

1. Notification Center
2. Closures
3. Delegate pattern

The right way is not a simple choice.  It really depends on the details.  You mention making an API call.  Assuming this is all managed in a separate object and not coded into your view controller code, I would have the object making the API call post a notification and the view controllers can each listen and do whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways to do this, one is using Delegates another one is Closures

Comment: check this link ---- https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: You can (and should) use the [edit] link below an answer to modify the content, rather than appending additional info in a comment. Comments are only meant for clarification and may be removed. But please take a moment to review the site's guidelines for answer in the [help]. All relevant information belongs in the answer, without requiring a link to an outside source. The Q&A information on this site should remain valid "for eternity"- links to outside material may become invalid, reducing the value of a contribution. So please expand on your answer, including relevant material from the link.